# How to prevent "tab" action triggered by iOS uikeyboard arrows?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uikeyboard

I have an HTML form, and on iOS specifically, I need to prevent the user from "tabbing" through the inputs when a modal is present.

I put quotes around "tabbing" because the iOS keyboard does not have a standard `tab` key, it uses prev/next arrows in a toolbar above the keyboard. (see image below)

[image]

There are no DOM events attached to these keys, so reading in `e.keyCode` and using `e.preventDefault()` are not options. Any ideas?

Comment: `$(document).bind('keydown', ...)`, `mousedown`, `touchstart`? Some of this event is fired?

Comment: @spirit nope, like I said in the post, these arrows do not trigger any DOM events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended implementing was something like the following:

**HTML**

```
<!-- modal content -->
<div class="search-modal">
  <input type="search" id="search-input" />
  <input type="text" onfocus="refocus('search-input')" style="opacity:0;" />
</div>

<!-- main page content -->
<div class="page-body">
  <input type="text" name="fname" />
  <input type="text" name="lname" />
  <input type="email" name="email" />
  <input type="tel" name="phone" />
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function refocus(id){
  document.getElementById(id).focus();
}
```

Whenever the "next" arrow is used, the invisible input gains focus. It immediately throws focus back on the original input; thus preventing non-modal inputs from gaining focus.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don’t have iOS to test. But I think you can try following:

1. disable all inputs except the first one.
2. after user entered some information and you validate it, enable next input
3. and so on.

A little wierd, but it may work =).

**PS**. Just realized. Did you mean than when a modal is present user is able to switch to inputs "under" the modal?

In that case, you must force `focus()` on the first element of your modal form, so "tabbing" will work in your new form.

Comment: These are good suggestions, thank you, but I have found another workaround with a little less overhead. And yes, the issue was focus of the under-modal input fields.

Comment: @SteamDev, so maybe you wil post your own answer?